# How to verify action passed into function was called?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I'm struggling with a unit test using Moq to isolate the BL from the DataAccess. Consider the following business logic:

```
public class MyBusinessLogic
{

private IDataAccess _dataAccess;

public MyBusinessLogic(IDataAccess dataAccess)
{
    _dataAccess = dataAccess;
}

public string SendEmail(string username)
{
    var emailAddress = _dataAccess.RunCommand<CommandDetails>("GetEmailAddressForUser", AddParametersToGetEmailAddress, new CommandDetails{Username = username});

    // do some send email stuff...

    return string.Concat("Email sent to ", emailAddress);
}

private void AddParametersToGetEmailAddress(IDbCommand command, CommandDetails details)
{
    var p = command.CreateParameter();
    p.ParameterName = "username";
    p.Value = details.Username;
    command.Parameters.Add(p);
}
}
```

A set of parameter details

```
public class CommandDetails
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
}
```

And a DataAccess interface

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    string RunCommand<TCommandDetails>(string command, Action<IDbCommand, TCommandDetails> addParameters, TCommandDetails details);
}
```

I have a test

```
var username = @"joebloggs";

var mock = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
mock.Setup(x => x.RunCommand<CommandDetails>(
    It.Is<string>(commandString => commandString == "GetEmailAddressForUser"),
    It.IsAny<Action<IDbCommand,CommandDetails>>(),
    It.Is<CommandDetails>(details => details.Username == username)))
.Returns("joebloggs@hotmail.com");

var businessLogic = new MyBusinessLogic(mock.Object);   

var message = businessLogic.SendEmail(username);

Assert.AreEqual("Email sent to joebloggs@hotmail.com", message);
```

This is great, it proves that the SP was called and the email was sent to the address returned.

However, it does not prove that the `AddParametersToGetEmailAddress` method was called. For all we know the SP is being called with no parameters.

How can I modify my setup to only return the email address the username parameter has been set on the command?

Answer (score 1):

`AddParametersToGetEmailAddress` won't be called because you're mocking the method (`RunCommand`) that would call it.

To achieve what (I think) you want you can add a callback to the method setup that will invoke your action, and then check the value of the `CommandDetails` afterwards:

```
var mockDbCommand = new Mock<IDbCommand>();

mock.Setup(x => x.RunCommand<CommandDetails>(
           It.Is<string>(commandString => commandString == "GetEmailAddressForUser"),
           It.IsAny<Action<IDbCommand,CommandDetails>>(),
           It.Is<CommandDetails>(details => details.Username == username)))
    .Callback<string, Action<IDbCommand,CommandDetails>, CommandDetails((s,a,d) => WrapAction(mockDbCommand.Object, d, a))
    .Returns("joebloggs@hotmail.com");

...

void WrapAction(IDbCommand dbCommand, CommandDetails commandDetails, Action<IDbCommand,CommandDetails> action)
{
    // Call the action, which will be AddParametersToGetEmailAddress
    action(dbCommand, commandDetails);

    // Assert that dbCommand has the username parameter
}
```

Note that you'll need to create `mockDbCommand` to pass to the action.

Comment: What I'm trying to test is that the correct method was passed into the dependency as an argument - correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe your WrapAction proves that?

Comment: It does if you instead test that your code *does* the correct thing, rather than that specific method was called, since that's what really matters in the end.  If you *really* want to make sure a particular method is called, you'll need to abstract it with an interface and inject that into `MyBusinessLogic`